# Android App built with cordova keeps crashing while using the app

Tags: android, cordova

Good day, please may i get some assistance with an application i'm building. The app is Android based built with cordova 9, i will attach the programs spec below. While the app opens and works fine, i have a problem navigating backwards, the mainview has a map with my current location then i have a tracking page where i can select a friend and it opens another view which has a map as well now from that screen some time when i try to go to the mainview app crashes.

**Project Spec**

Android 9,
Cordova 9,
HandlebarJS,
google maps cordova plugin, 
Transistorsoft Geolocation Plugin

Any ideas or solutions will be appreciated, if i left out something please let me know i'll gladly provide.

LOG

````
    Process: xxxxxxxxxxxxx.app, PID: 27090
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {xxxxxxxxxxx.app/xxxxxxxxxx.app.MainActivity}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4681)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4640)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4614)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4566)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2021)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
     Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:757)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValueIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:785)
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.onPause(PluginManager.java:209)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.handlePause(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:435)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onPause(CordovaActivity.java:245)
        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7501)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1421)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4640) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4614) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4566) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2021) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)```
````